# Weird behaviour with fscanf in C program

Tags: c

I would like to know in below code snippet why `fscanf` is throwing -1 in the middle of the execution and due to this I am not getting desired output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    char fname[200], cmd[200];
    int i=0,j=0;
    system("ls /tmp/*.msg -1rt > /tmp/xyz.txt");
    fp=fopen("/tmp/xyz.txt","r+");
    if(fp!=NULL){
        i=fscanf(fp,"%s",fname);
        while(i!=EOF){
            sleep(2);
            printf("Filename is:'%s'\n",fname); 
            sprintf(cmd, "rm -rf %s; touch /tmp/a_%d_new.msg",fname,j++);
            system(cmd);
            memset(fname, 0, 200);
            memset(cmd,0, 200);
            system("ls /tmp/*.msg -rt1 > /tmp/xyz.txt");
            i=fscanf(fp,"%s",fname);// fscanf will return error after some iterations
            printf("The I Value is: '%d'\n",i);
        }
    }
    if(fp!=NULL)
        fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Reproducing steps:

1. Create a /tmp/xyz.txt file (no data)
2. > xyz.txt ( make it empty if any data there)
3. rm -rf *.msg
4. touch a.msg b.msg c.msg d.msg e.msg f.msg

Here I am expecting gracefull exit from while loop . in current scenario it is not happening due to fscanf function.

Comment: Please show what data file contains .

Comment: What do you expect to read from an empty file?

Comment: The normal return value from `fscanf`, when the input is exhausted, is to return `EOF`, which is `-1`.  So the loop should exit right after printing `-1`.

Comment: It will contain file name which is generated in the code . i.e./tmp/a_5_new.msg
/tmp/a_0_new.msg

Comment: sprintf(cmd, "rm -rf %s; touch /tmp/a_%d_new.msg",fname,j++); system("ls /tmp/*.msg -rt1 > /tmp/xyz.txt"); Kindly see above two lines in the code to see how the files are generated and complete path of the generated files is stored in xyz.txt file.

Comment: It works fine for me. I prints the file names and last iteration it prints `The I Value is: '-1'` and then exits gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me that I did a better job at explaining this the second time, so here is my better explanation:

`FILE` is a stateful device that includes an `EOF` flag and a buffer. If when buffering, end of file is reached then it might be queued in the buffer, and the buffer won't be updated until it's exhausted. What is essentially happening is a copy of part of the file is made in memory, and when you make external changes to that file the copy in memory becomes out of sync.

The solution is to synchronise the buffer somehow. If you change the file position, then the standard library will have no choice but to update the cached version and reset the `EOF` flag. You have two options:

- `rewind` makes sense if you intend to use `<` the way you have, because you're overwriting the file each loop, so you'll want to read from the start of the file.
- `fgetpos`, followed by your `fscanf`, followed by `fsetpos` only makes sense if you intended to use `<<` instead of `<`, because `<<` concatenates to the end of the file, so when `fscanf` fails you'll be able to pick up where you left off *after* you update the file.

In my first answer, I also posed a question about the design you have chosen. The gist of that is, whichever of the above choices you make, `fscanf` should not normally produce an `EOF` value unless one of your `system` calls fails to create files. I think you have gathered this based on a conversation we had below. Unfortunately I can't make any suggestions unless you give a more broad overview on what problem your program is supposed to solve... All I can say is, `while(i!=EOF)` doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Having said that, it's unusual (kind of wasteful, possibly erroneous and insecure) for C code to be calling `system`... Again, I need to know what problem your program is expected to solve to make a better suggestion.

Comment: Note that the 1..n-char buffer used by `ungetc()` can be **distinct** from the buffer assigned via `setbuf()` / `setvbuf()`. (It's actually easier to implement that way.)

Comment: @DevSolar I avoided that topic as it didn't seem necessary to understand what the problem could be. You did a much better job than I could've, so you got my +1, hopefully to keep that comment as supplementary for future readers. I'm not convinced that it'd be significantly easier. If the buffer is implemented as a circular array, moving the cursor backwards one step seems trivial. I suppose the syscall would then have to support circular arrays, multiple syscalls would be required or there might be other complexities I've overlooked. My understanding of kernel land is unfortunately obscure.

Comment: why the fscanf is returning EOF when updating file which is already opened with a file pointer. What are the side impacts if we update a file for a opened file pointer.

Comment: i just give a try and updated code with >> instead of > and observed fscanf is not returning any error but loop is indefinite so in this scenario would i be able to reach EOF ?.system("ls /tmp/*.msg -rt1 >> /tmp/abc.txt");

Comment: If you erase the file prior to concatenation (e.g. using `>`) and you don't `rewind` the file, then you will get erratic behaviour; sometimes the first line might be partial, other times `EOF` will be returned. This is what you're seeing. If you don't erase the file (e.g. using `>>` to append, instead) then your loop might not reach `EOF`. Isn't that to be expected, because immediately prior to the test you write data to the file? If you want to reach `EOF`, don't write to the file immediately before the test. **What actual problem are you trying to solve?**

Comment: @seb i am agree with you as if i perform rewind(fp) before fscanf  in this case also i won't be able to reach EOF and loop will go continuously due to EOF  flag reset by moving file pointer  at the beginning.As i mentioned in my earlier comments   " why the fscanf is returning EOF when updating file which is already opened with a file pointer. What are the side impacts if we update a file for a opened file pointer."

Comment: @seb : Do you have any answer of my question?                                                                                                 why the fscanf is returning EOF when updating file which is already opened with a file pointer. What are the side impacts if we update a file for a opened file pointer

Comment: @user2997518 I already explained in my answer what I think is going on. Nonetheless, I've updated my answer with a more general overview, in case you couldn't understand my more detailed explanation. Speaking of that, if you don't understand something I wrote, don't just ignore what I wrote and re-ask the question; quote the part that you don't understand and ask a question about that, instead.

Comment: @sebi : I understood about   changing the file pointer through rewind will reset the EOF flag but couldn't understood about synchronization of buffer concept with respect of this issue. Do you mean to say it is regarding if we update a file for a opened file pointer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97406/discussion-between-user2997518-and-seb).